# com.android.volley.ServerError error instanceof VolleyError

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, build.gradle

Good morning

I have a problem 
"**com.android.volley.ServerError**"

This is my `build.gradle` file 'app'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.azizsana.espacemembre2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':volley')
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

File: `build.gradle` Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In logcat, i see "

Failed to find layer

`(com.example.azizsana.espacemembre2/com.example.azizsana.espacemembre2.RegisterActivity#0) in layer parent (no-parent).`

Comment: Please paste your error log

Comment: have you decleraed your RegisterActivity in manifest file??

Comment: Check your Parameters at first and do debug

Comment: error log please

Comment: The response is 404 that means there is no api exits to that path http://192.168.3.101/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php

Comment: check if the link you're providing is accessible ! try opening it with a browser and see if you get a response back

Comment: Yes, i declared my  RegisterActivity in manifest file
 <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme5"/>

Comment: Error 404 means this is a server side error. please check your server side code

Comment: Yes, i tried in a browser and it is run fine but i need to change ip address to localhost with port like that "http://localhost:8081/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php"

Comment: @yiinsskibare i think you have to delete implementation project(':volley') check my answer

Comment: Paraskevas Ntsounos i try it right now and i tell you what it will become

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete this line:

```
implementation project(':volley')
```

Because you use it below:

```
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Try to update grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.azizsana.espacemembre2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation project(':volley') <---- You dont need this line
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Gradle was building indefinitely
But now i  have deletes this line:
implementation project(':volley')

But i have always the error " com.android.volley.ServerError "

Comment: @yiinsskibare yes remove this line so now it is fixed?

Comment: And in log file, i see Volley: [542] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.0.2.2/android/tutoEspaceMembre/login.php

Comment: @yiinsskibare this error comes from your api, so check this api if its work properly first and then add in your project and be sure that this end point exist in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Delete these two line

```
implementation project(':volley')
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

and add Google volley

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

You are getting a 404 error that means the api/end point is not exits.

Check end-point you are requesting

current end point is `http://192.168.3.101/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php`.

If you are able to hit the end-point from your laptop/desktop and not able to hit it from android then,

These are multiple reasons for this.

If you are running the api in your system and the android app is running in a simulator of the same system then you need to change the IP address to `10.0.2.2` ( Use 10.0.2.2 for default AVD and 10.0.3.2 for genymotion. ).

Second case is that if you are running the app in your phone and api in any other computer make sure both are connected to the same network, Because you are dealing with IP address

Comment: I am able to hit the end-point in my laptop and i am not able to hit it from android so i need to change ip address to 127.0.0.1 mean that localhost

Comment: Okay then follow the steps i mentioned above. You can easily solve it. I was having same error before @yiinsskibare

Comment: @yiinsskibare Your server is running on the same machine you are running the emulator ? Are you running the app on emulator  or in phone ?

Comment: the android app is running in a simulator and i also try it in my physical phone. And my phone and my computer are connected to the same network

Comment: yes then you just need to change the IP to 127.0.0.1 @yiinsskibare

Comment: If you are running in the emulator in which the Server is running then you have to use 127.0.0.1 IP address if its on your phone you need to use the server IP address @yiinsskibare

Comment: oh really, so i'm not only

Comment: These are the common error people make when they start working server based android app. @yiinsskibare

Comment: @yiinsskibare if its give you the same error again use this IP address 10.0.2.2

Comment: @yiinsskibare Use 10.0.2.2 for default AVD and 10.0.3.2 for genymotion.

Comment: Gradle was building indefinitely
But now I have been able to delete these two line
implementation project(':volley')
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
and i can not change implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
to implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
So i kept implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

Comment: I also change the IP address to 10.0.2.2 ( Use 10.0.2.2 for default AVD)
(i use Nexus 4 API 26 Android 8.0.0)
But  i  have always the error " com.android.volley.ServerError "

Comment: @yiinsskibare Are u getting the same error or any different one ?

Comment: And in log file, i see Volley: [542] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.0.2.2/android/tutoEspaceMembre/login.php

Comment: But i have this file in this location 192.168.3.101/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php And i can launch it in web browser

Comment: @yiinsskibare Right now there is no problem in adding the discrepancies to your project only problem is where you are sending the request. So update your question with the code which is used to send the request to the server

Answer (score 0):

Base on your error code there may be issue in your backend side.
You may check more form https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html and http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html this documents.

```
Unexpected response code 404 for http://192.168.3.101/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php
```

**404 Status code means :**

```
Not found 404
The server has not found anything matching the URI given
```

Comment: alright, i check this documents
Yes, base on this documents, 404 status code means " The server has not found anything matching the URI given" 

But i have this file in this location http://192.168.3.101/android/tutoEspaceMembre/register.php

And i can launch it in web browser